# log4perl multiple configs in a single conf file

Tags: perl, log4perl

Can i have multiple configurations specified in a single conf file?

i have specified something like this

```
log4perl.category.xml_script                = DEBUG, LOGFILE_XML_SCRIPT
log4perl.category.xml_script.XML_script_lib = DEBUG, LOGFILE_SCRIPT_LIB
log4perl.category.addrdec2xml               = DEBUG, LOGFILE_ADDRDEC2XML
log4perl.oneMessagePerAppender              = 1
```

*xml_script* and *addrdec2xml* are 2 independent scripts.

```
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_XML_SCRIPT                           = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_XML_SCRIPT.filename                  = xml_script.log
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_XML_SCRIPT.mode                      = overwrite
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_XML_SCRIPT.layout                    = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_XML_SCRIPT.layout.ConversionPattern  = %p %F(%L): [%c] %m%n

log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_SCRIPT_LIB                           = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_SCRIPT_LIB.filename                  = xml_script_lib.log
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_SCRIPT_LIB.mode                      = overwrite
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_SCRIPT_LIB.layout                    = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_SCRIPT_LIB.layout.ConversionPattern  = %p %F(%L): [%c] %m%n

log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_ADDRDEC2XML                          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_ADDRDEC2XML.filename                 = addrdec2xml.log
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_ADDRDEC2XML.mode                     = overwrite
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_ADDRDEC2XML.layout                   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.LOGFILE_ADDRDEC2XML.layout.ConversionPattern = %p %F(%L): [%c]%n%m%n
```

When i run the scripts independently the other log file get cleaned. :(
Any suggestions appreciated. I dont want to have multiple conf, so please suggest solution with a single conf file.

Comment: You could use [`JSON`](http://p3rl.org/JSON) or [`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML) for configurations

Comment: It is not about getting output, but logging debug levels. I did not get your answer. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Change the mode to append and make sure you are going to invoke the logger like this:

```
my $logger = get_logger('xml_script');

my $logger = get_logger('addrdec2xml');
```

Comment: Did you changed the mode to append?

Comment: I dont want append. That beats the purpose. The logs should log only when the respective loggers are invoked irrespective of what is defined in the config. and when they log they should not append but overwrite

Comment: "When i run the scripts independently the other log file get cleaned. " because the mode is overwrite. The loggers gets initialized and all the logfiles gets truncated. You have to spearate the config or create the appenders on the fly.